# Pattern matching for profile in Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: config, spring-cloud

### Context

I am attempting to separate configuration information for our applications using the pattern-matching feature in Spring Cloud Config Server. I have created a repo for "production" environment with a property file `floof.yaml`. I have created a repo for "development" environment with a property file `floof-dev.yaml`.

My server config:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: "bluemoon"
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file://${user.home}/tmp/prod
          repos:
            development:
              pattern:
                - \*/dev
              uri: file://${user.home}/tmp/dev
```

After starting the server instance, I can successfully retrieve the config content using curl, and can verify which content was served by referring to the "source" element as well as the values for the properties themselves.

### Expected Behavior

When I fetch `http://localhost:8080/floof/prod` I expect to see the source "$HOME/tmp/prod/floof.yaml" and the values from that source, and the actual results match that expectation.

When I fetch `http://localhost:8080/floof/dev` I expect to see the source "$HOME/tmp/dev/floof-dev.yaml" and the values from that source, but the actual result is the "production" file and contents (the same as if I had fetched `.../floof/prod` instead.

### My Questions

1. Is my expectation of behavior incorrect? I assume not since there is an example in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) in the "Git backend" section that suggests separation by profile is a thing.
2. Is my server config incorrectly specifying the "development" repo? I turned up the logging verbosity in the server instance and saw nothing in there that called attention to itself in terms of misconfiguration.
3. Are the property files subject to a naming convention that I'm not following?

Comment: You're describing the behavior of if it didn't match, use the default. Maybe a problem with the pattern? This is the pattern matching library: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is how I resolved::
[spring cloud config pattern match for profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487146/spring-cloud-config-pattern-match-for-profile)

Also, check if you are using Brixton.M5 version.

After some debugging on the PatternMatching source code here is how I resolved the issue: You can choose one of the two ways.

```
application.yml
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://xxxx@github/sample/cloud-config-properties.git
          repos:
           development:
            pattern: '*/development' ## give in quotes
            uri: ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git
```

OR

```
development:
  pattern: xx*/development,*/development ##since it is not allowed to have a value starting with a wildcard( '*' )after pattern I first gave a generic matching but the second value is */development. Since pattern takes multiple values, the second pattern will match with the profile.
  uri: ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git
```

pattern: `*/development`.Error on yml file- expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found but found `/`.

The reason the profile pattern git repo was not identified because : although spring allows multiple array values for pattern beginning with a '-' in the yml file, the pattern matcher was taking the '-' as string to be matched. i.e it is looking for a pattern `'-*/development'` instead of `'*/development'`.

```
 repos:
    development:
     pattern:
      -*/development    
      -*/staging
```

Another issue i observed was, I was getting a compilation error on yml file if i had to mention the pattern array as `'- */development'` - note space after hyphen(which is meant to show that it can hold multiple values as array) and start with a `'*/development'` with an error: expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found but found `/`

```
repos:
        development:
         pattern:
          - */development    
          - */staging
```