# spring cloud config pattern match for profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud, config, spring-cloud

I am trying to implement the pattern matching feature of spring cloud config based on the different profiles for an application. Based on the documentation in http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_environment_repository it is possible to match the repositories based on profiles. Below is my config server application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://xxxx@github/sample/cloud-config-properties.git
          repos:
            development:
             pattern:
               -*/development    
               -*/staging 
             uri: ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git
            test:
             pattern: 
               -*/test
               -*/perf
             uri: ${HOME}/Documents/cloud-config-sample-test
```

I have an config client application "user" and have user.properties, user-development.properties, user-test.properties

Based on the documentation - irrespective of the application name , if the pattern matches */development i,e localhost:8888/user/development or localhost:8888/demo/development my config server should match the profile pattern and fetch the appropriate properties.
Ex: http://localhost:8888/demo/development
I should get demo-development.properties from ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git

But in my application, the default uri is used for all the profiles i.e my property file demo.properties is returned from 
uri: ssh://xxxx@github/sample/cloud-config-properties.git

Any pointers on this?

EDIT:
pom.xml

```
<parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>Brixton.M5</version>
      <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots-continuous</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots Continuous</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-continuous-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Brixton.M5

pom.xml:

<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>Brixton.M5</version>
   <relativePath /> 
 </parent>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some debugging  on the PatternMatching source code here is how I resolved the issue: You can choose one of the two ways.

```
application.yml
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://xxxx@github/sample/cloud-config-properties.git
          repos:
           development:
            pattern: '*/development' ## give in quotes
            uri: ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git
```

OR

```
development:
  pattern: xx*/development,*/development ##since it is not allowed to have a value starting with a wildcard( '*' )after pattern I first gave a generic matching but the second value is */development. Since pattern takes multiple values, the second pattern will match with the profile
  uri: ssh://git@xxxgithub.com/development.git
```

pattern: */development.Error on yml file- expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found but found /.

The reason the profile pattern git repo was not identified because : although spring allows multiple array values for pattern beginning with a '-' in the yml file, the pattern matcher was taking the '-' as string to be matched. i.e it is looking for a pattern `'-*/development'` instead of `'*/development'`.

```
   repos:
    development:
     pattern:
      -*/development    
      -*/staging
```

Another issue i observed was, I was getting a compilation error on yml file if i had to mention the pattern array as `'- */development'` - note space after hyphen(which is meant to show that it can hold multiple values as array) and start with a '*/development' with an error: expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found but found /

```
 repos:
        development:
         pattern:
          - */development    
          - */staging
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't see that earlier. It's a YML issue, strings that start with `*` need to be surrounded by `'`.